# How do I call another function in the same javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript

I like to organize my javascript in namespace style like below. What I want to know : is there another (shorter?) way to call `myFirstFunction()` from `mySecondFunction()`? I tried `this.myFirstFunction()` and it's not working so maybe there's some kind of mysterious trick here that I don't know.

```
var myNameSpace = {
    myFirstFunction: function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    },
    mySecondFunction: function(){
        myNameSpace.myFirstFunction();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help as usual, people of SO! :)

Comment: Your example is correct, it should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As written in your example code, `this.myFirstFunction()` would work. Your code is likely simplified to illustrate your problem, so it would probably help to see the actual code to tell why it doesn't work with `this`.

One possible reason that it fails would be if the code where you call `this.myFirstFunction()` is inside a closure. If so, `this` would be a reference to the closing function, not your namespace and would therefore fail. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3J6J3/) for a contrived example based on your code to see what I mean. Again, having a look at the actual code would probably be helpful to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Good simple answer. I understood everything with your jsfiddle example. Thanks, you just made my js code a little bit more clean! And you were right, I simplified my code to post it here, and my call to the function was in a closure. I didn't know that it would affect the "this" keyword. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, Gabriel. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion to use 'this' should work. i.e.:

```
var myNameSpace = {
    myFirstFunction: function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    },
    mySecondFunction: function(){
        this.myFirstFunction();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
myNameSpace.mySecondFunction() // "Hello World!".
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be shorter maybe you should consider the following pattern:

[Javascript Design Pattern Suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015844/javascript-designpattern-suggestion-needed/4016084#4016084)

basically for your example:

```
var myNameSpace = (function()
{
    function _myFirstFunction(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    }

    function _mySecondFunction(){
        _myFirstFunction();
    }

    return {
        MyFirstFunction : _myFirstFunction,    
        MySecondFunction : _mySecondFunction
    };
})();
```

I find this to be the cleanest pattern, also providing "private/public" variables in javascript that's otherwise pretty much impossible

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the `this` keyword should work fine. If you explicitly call `myNameSpace.mySecondFunction()` then `this.myFirstFunction()` will execute as intended.

If you are using `myNameSpace.mySecondFunction` as an event handler it likely will not. In the case of an event handler you would need some way to refer to the namespace you want to use. A lot of JavaScript frameworks provide a way to define what the `this` keyword refers to. For example, in [MooTools](http://mootools.net) you can do `myNameSpace.mySecondFunction.bind(myNameSpace)` which will cause `this` to refer to `myNameSpace` inside `mySecondFunction`. If you are not using a framework you could make your event handler an anonymous function like:

```
document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  myNameSpace.mySecondFunction.call(myNameSpace);
});
```

For more information on the call method I would refer to the [MDC page for the call function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or you could use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which behaves similarly to call but passing an array of arguments for the second paramter rather than having a varargs like approach for additional parameters.

All of these suggestions are predicated on defining your namespace as [@Harnish suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083669/how-do-i-call-another-function-in-the-same-javascript-namespace/4083841#4083841):

```
var myNameSpace = {
  myFirstFunction: function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
  },
  mySecondFunction: function(){
    this.myFirstFunction();
  }
}
```

For more information about JavaScript function binding I'd highly suggest reading [Justin's article on Function scope and binding in JavaScript](http://alternateidea.com/blog/articles/2007/7/18/javascript-scope-and-binding)

Answer (score 0):

## If you are attaching to event:

possible issue could be if you are attaching Namespace's function to event, like:

```
$(el).on("click", nameSpace.myFunc);

....

nameSpace = {

    myFunc: function(){
       this.anotherFunc();
    }

}
```

that will throw error.

## Solution 1

You may  change `this.anotherFunc()` with `nameSpace.anotherFunc()`

## Solution 2

You might change

```
$(el).on("click", nameSpace.myFunc);
// to ----->
$(el).on("click", function(){ nameSpace.myFunc(); }  );
```